# Unexpected ManipulationCompleted, first stroke drawing cut short

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm trying to implement freehand drawing on a Canvas-derived class. I've implemented handlers for the ManipulationXXX events, they go like this:

```
private void OnManipulationStarted(object o, ManipulationStartedEventArgs a)
{
    Point pt = GetManPoint(a.ManipulationOrigin, a.ManipulationContainer);
    Debug.WriteLine("Down at {0},{1}", pt.X, pt.Y);
    m_Strokes.Add(m_Stroke = new Stroke(pt, this));
    CaptureMouse();
    a.Handled = true;
}

private void OnManipulationDelta(object o, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs a)
{
    if (m_Stroke != null)
    {
        Point pt = GetManPoint(a.ManipulationOrigin, a.ManipulationContainer);
        Debug.WriteLine("Delta at {0},{1}", pt.X, pt.Y);
        m_Stroke.AddPoint(pt);
        a.Handled = true;
    }
}

private void OnManipulationCompleted(object o, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs a)
{
    if (m_Stroke != null)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Up");
        ReleaseMouseCapture();
        Point[] Pts = m_Stroke.Points;
        m_Stroke = null;
        a.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Haven't tried on actual device, but on the simulator, there's one persistent issue. For the first attempt at a stroke, the `ManipulationCompleted` event is fired right after `ManipulationStarted`. Even though I don't release the mouse button. I can tell by the debug output - there's "Up" right after "Down". The subsequent strokes draw fine (if somewhat laggy).

Anyone else familiar with this? Is that a simulator-only thing, or does the device do the same?

The Stroke class that I'm referring to here is a thin wrapper over `Polyline`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced the same behavior on Simulator. But on real device it's works without problem(You can test here on real device http://rda.cellulardata.com/devices)